# CONFLUENT -- Java Error --- Error:(16,114) java: illegal escape character

Tags: java, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am having trouble with Java escape characters. I have these from Confluent ccloud configs example.
but does not work . both give me the same error message Error:(16,114) java: illegal escape character

```
props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username\="<abcdfg>" password\="<xyz123>";");

props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule \
username=\"abcdfg\" password=\"xyz123\";");
```

Comment: Where exactly is (16, 114)? The backslash right before the newline (on the 2nd line)?

Answer (score 2):

**Hello**, change `";"` to `\";\""`. Otherwise your IDEA thinks that the string will end there, even though it is not.

Have fun, I hope I could help you!